# Most browsers automatically replace some characters based on set language?

Tags: html, browser, unicode

In most browsers (I checked Chrome, Firefox and Opera), setting lang="ro" will automatically replace some cedille characters with other ones.

Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/dhtfb190/13

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ro">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="font: 500% georgia;">&scedil;ș&scedil;ș&#350;Ș&#350;ŞȘ</div>
</body>

</html>
```

This does not happen in Edge or IE or if the language is set to "en" or not set. Also, this does not happen for all fonts. For example, if happens for Georgia but it does not for Arial. But Georgia has all those characters because they get displayed with lang="en".

Even with escaped instantiation, it does the same.

Where is this documented ? I searched a lot of internet and only found some examples for Chinese language replacing some symbols. How can I see which characters get replaced ? Why is it only doing it for some fonts ?

Comment: Can you describe more clearly how what gets replaced by what?

Comment: "ş" to 'ș', "ţ" to 'ț', "Ţ" to 'Ț', "Ş" to 'Ș'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glyphs ("the printed characters") depends on the language. This is a good typographical rule, and good fonts supports such characteristic.

So you get the "ro" variant of specific characters.

It is "sort of documented". It is in one section of font definitions (and only newer font format support them), but it is difficult to extract such data. There are few Python libraries. [BTW: in my TODO list there is also a project to display variants of characters].

Maybe if you look at the design page of your font, you may find some information about which languages have variants.

This is more visible on Indic languages, where ligatures depend on the exact language and the epoc of text. On Latin characters, it is mostly a trivia question. Unicode standard cites different inclination of accents between French and Polish, within same font.

ADDENDUM:

The best information I can find, it is in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/gsub, e.g. in the following quote, but also repeated on the text:

> The ScriptList identifies all the scripts and language systems in the font that use glyph substitutes.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it detects the language and displays a different set of characters from the typeface.

Like some Typefaces do not support äÄüÜöÖ and will display □□□□□□ instead.
Georgia (and other typefaces as well) support Russian, and will automatically switch their characters.

You can dive deeper and check in a Text Editor, like MS Word or InDesign, and see that a single character can look differently, also known as Glyphs.

https://helpx.adobe.com/incopy/using/glyphs-special-characters.html You can check it out here, when you scroll down a bit there is a screenshot when they're inside the Glyph window with the dropdown menu open. You can see there is an option for Cyrillic. So RO uses a different set of glyphs than EN.

You can view this page on Georgia and see they have a Language Script Tag für Cyrillic. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/georgia